# Display a particular field in a view by a comma separated values using custom code

Tags: 7, views

For a partular view  say "abc" I have created a view.

Now I want a particular field in that view as comma separated values.

How can I achieve this. Can I do this with custom coding only for that particular field.

I am learning drupal custom coding. so If this is possible through custom coding Please give me sample code.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a template for the field you want to modify.

Click on link Advanced -> Themes -> Information, while editing the view, and select the right template and file name.
Then, in the template you can modify the output of the field.